# Why svg animation is not displaying button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Im created  some `svg` animation and  I added for  my Web application ,now  when I click the `Add Score button` after I try to  display this animation same page move to top (like Facebook text delight animation-im attached sample image  ),

(look and click snippet, animation is already displayed- without button click ,I don't want to do that  )

**2nd issue** , Im click the button I want to this play that animation and after redirect next page ,

its not working for me, please help me to fix it

```css
svg{
  background: transparent;

  padding-top:-20px;
}

.conf0{fill:#FC6394;}
.conf1{fill:#EF3C8A;}
.conf2{fill:#5ADAEA;}
.conf3{fill:#974CBE;}
.conf4{fill:#3CBECD;}
.conf5{fill:#813BBE;}
.conf6{fill:#F9B732;}
.conf7{display:none;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.conf8{fill:none;stroke:#F9B732;stroke-width:9;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}


.confetti-cone{
  transform-origin: 200px 50px;
  animation:confetti-cone1 1.2s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes confetti-cone1{
  0%{
    transform:translate(40px, 95px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  15%{
    transform:translate(10px, 145px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1.1, 0.85);

  }
  100%{
    transform:translate(40px, 105px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
}

#yellow-strip {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#F9B732;
  stroke-width:9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  animation: confdash 1.2s ease infinite;
}


@keyframes confdash {
  0%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(-30px, 30px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  2%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(-30px, 30px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  35%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:900;
    transform:translate(-2px, 0px);
    opacity:1;
  }

  85%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    transform:translate(1px, -5px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  90%{
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    transform:translate(2px, -8px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(2px, -8px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}



#conf-a{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confa 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confa {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  15%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(25px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  80%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(33px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(37px, -23px) scale(0.5)rotate(230deg);
  }
}


#conf-b{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confb 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confb {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  12%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(25px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(33px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(37px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(240deg);
  }
}

#conf-c{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confc 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confc {
  0%{
    opacity:0.7;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  18%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(5px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(13px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(17px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(230deg);
  }
}

#conf-d{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confd 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confd {
  0%{
    opacity:0.7;
    transform: translate(-20px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  18%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(-5px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(-8px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-10px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(230deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="footer-tab">
  <!--button-->
  <div class="crtnewgrp-btn">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <a href="addacore" style="text-decoration: none;"> <div class="p-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Add score</button></div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--/button-->
</div>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 1200 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 800;" xml:space="preserve">
       <g class="confetti-cone">
        <path class="conf0" d="M131.5,172.6L196,343c2.3,6.1,11,6.1,13.4,0l65.5-170.7L131.5,172.6z"/>
        <path class="conf1" d="M131.5,172.6L196,343c2.3,6.1,11,6.1,13.4,0l6.7-17.5l-53.6-152.9L131.5,172.6z"/>

        <path class="conf2" d="M274.2,184.2c-1.8,1.8-4.2,2.9-7,2.9l-129.5,0.4c-5.4,0-9.8-4.4-9.8-9.8c0-5.4,4.4-9.8,9.9-9.9l129.5-0.4
         c5.4,0,9.8,4.4,9.8,9.8C277,180,275.9,182.5,274.2,184.2z"/>
        <polygon class="conf3" points="231.5,285.4 174.2,285.5 143.8,205.1 262.7,204.7    "/>
        <path class="conf4" d="M166.3,187.4l-28.6,0.1c-5.4,0-9.8-4.4-9.8-9.8c0-5.4,4.4-9.8,9.9-9.9l24.1-0.1c0,0-2.6,5-1.3,10.6
         C161.8,183.7,166.3,187.4,166.3,187.4z"/>
        <ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -89.8523 231.0278)" class="conf2" cx="233.9" cy="224" rx="5.6" ry="5.6"/>
        <path class="conf5" d="M143.8,205.1l5.4,14.3c6.8-2.1,14.4-0.5,19.7,4.8c7.7,7.7,7.6,20.1-0.1,27.8c-1.7,1.7-3.7,3-5.8,4l11.1,29.4
         l27.7,0l-28-80.5L143.8,205.1z"/>
        <path class="conf2" d="M169,224.2c-5.3-5.3-13-6.9-19.7-4.8l13.9,36.7c2.1-1,4.1-2.3,5.8-4C176.6,244.4,176.6,231.9,169,224.2z"/>
        <ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -119.0946 221.1253)" class="conf6" cx="207.4" cy="254.3" rx="11.3" ry="11.2"/>
      </g>

       <rect x="113.7" y="135.7" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -99.5348 209.1582)" class="conf7" width="178" height="178"/>
      <line class="conf7" x1="76.8" y1="224.7" x2="328.6" y2="224.7"/>
      <polyline class="conf7" points="202.7,350.6 202.7,167.5 202.7,98.9  "/>
          <!-- here comes the confettis-->

       <circle class="conf2" id="conf-b" cx="195.2" cy="232.6" r="5.1"/>
       <circle class="conf0" id="conf-b" cx="230.8" cy="219.8" r="5.4"/>
       <circle class="conf0" id="conf-c" cx="178.9" cy="160.4" r="4.2"/>
       <circle class="conf6" id="conf-d"cx="132.8" cy="123.6" r="5.4"/>
       <circle class="conf0" id="conf-d" cx="151.9" cy="105.1" r="5.4"/>

       <path class="conf0" id="conf-d" d="M129.9,176.1l-5.7,1.3c-1.6,0.4-2.2,2.3-1.1,3.5l3.8,4.2c1.1,1.2,3.1,0.8,3.6-0.7l1.9-5.5
        C132.9,177.3,131.5,175.7,129.9,176.1z"/>
       <path class="conf6" id="conf-b" d="M284.5,170.7l-5.4,1.2c-1.5,0.3-2.1,2.2-1,3.3l3.6,3.9c1,1.1,2.9,0.8,3.4-0.7l1.8-5.2
        C287.4,171.9,286.1,170.4,284.5,170.7z"/>
       <circle class="conf6" id="conf-c"cx="206.7" cy="144.4" r="4.5"/>
        <path class="conf2" id="conf-c" d="M176.4,192.3h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
        C179.3,191,178,192.3,176.4,192.3z"/>
       <path class="conf2" id="conf-b" d="M263.7,197.4h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
        C266.5,196.1,265.2,197.4,263.7,197.4z"/>
          <!-- yellow-strip-1-->
         <path id="yellow-strip" d="M179.7,102.4c0,0,6.6,15.3-2.3,25c-8.9,9.7-24.5,9.7-29.7,15.6c-5.2,5.9-0.7,18.6,3.7,28.2
        c4.5,9.7,2.2,23-10.4,28.2"/>
       <path class="conf8" id="yellow-strip" d="M252.2,156.1c0,0-16.9-3.5-28.8,2.4c-11.9,5.9-14.9,17.8-16.4,29c-1.5,11.1-4.3,28.8-31.5,33.4"/>
       <path class="conf0" id="conf-a" d="M277.5,254.8h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
        C280.4,253.5,279.1,254.8,277.5,254.8z"/>
       <path class="conf3" id="conf-c" d="M215.2,121.3L215.2,121.3c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3l0,0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7v0
        c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2l0,0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0h0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2v0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7l0,0
        c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1v0C212.5,119.8,214.5,119.8,215.2,121.3z"/>
       <path class="conf3" id="conf-b" d="M224.5,191.7L224.5,191.7c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3v0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7l0,0
        c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2h0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0l0,0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2l0,0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7v0
        c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1l0,0C221.7,190.2,223.8,190.2,224.5,191.7z"/>
       <path class="conf3" id="conf-a" d="M312.6,242.1L312.6,242.1c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3l0,0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7v0
        c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2l0,0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0h0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2v0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7l0,0
        c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1v0C309.9,240.6,311.9,240.6,312.6,242.1z"/>
       <path class="conf8" id="yellow-strip" d="M290.7,215.4c0,0-14.4-3.4-22.6,2.7c-8.2,6.2-8.2,23.3-17.1,29.4c-8.9,6.2-19.8-2.7-32.2-4.1
        c-12.3-1.4-19.2,5.5-20.5,10.9"/>

</svg>
```

this is a Facebook text delight animation example
[image]
 Thanks

Comment: `down voter  please explain why are you put down?`

Comment: Perhaps they downvoted because it was a little hard to understand your question. What is your problem? Can you try rewriting your question please?

Comment: It is still a little hard to understand. It sounds like you want the SVG to be hidden until you click the button. Then when you click the button, it plays the animation. When the animation is finished, you want to redirect to another page.  Is that correct?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau sir,you got it

Comment: Ok then. Then my answer should do what you need.

Comment: sir do you know how to make click the button before the redirect this `svg` animate auto `move to bottom to top `(just 1 second )

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry. Please try shorter sentences.

Comment: sir  you know face book new UI Features (Facebook text delight animation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156898/discussion-between-core114-and-paul-lebeau).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it something like this that you wanted?

1. We start with the SVG hidden with `display: none`.
2. When you click on the button, we add the `show` class to the SVG. That changes the `display` property to `block`. Making the SVG visible.
3. We also set up a timeout using `window.setTimeout()`. After a few seconds, it redirects to another page by setting `window.location.href`.

```js
var addScoreButton = document.getElementById("add-score-button");
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");


addScoreButton.addEventListener("click", addScoreClick);


function addScoreClick(evt)
{
  mysvg.classList.add("show");
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.alert("Redirecting to Google");
    //window.location.href="https://www.google.com";
  }, 3600);
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: none;
}

svg.show {
  display: block;
}


.conf0{fill:#FC6394;}
.conf1{fill:#EF3C8A;}
.conf2{fill:#5ADAEA;}
.conf3{fill:#974CBE;}
.conf4{fill:#3CBECD;}
.conf5{fill:#813BBE;}
.conf6{fill:#F9B732;}
.conf7{display:none;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.conf8{fill:none;stroke:#F9B732;stroke-width:9;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}


.confetti-cone {
  transform-origin: 200px 50px;
  animation:confetti-cone1 1.2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes confetti-cone1{
  0%{
    transform:translate(40px, 95px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  15%{
    transform:translate(10px, 145px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1.1, 0.85);

  }
  100%{
    transform:translate(40px, 105px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
}

#yellow-strip {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#F9B732;
  stroke-width:9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  animation: confdash 1.2s ease infinite;
}


@keyframes confdash {
  0%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(-30px, 30px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  2%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(-30px, 30px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  35%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:900;
    transform:translate(-2px, 0px);
    opacity:1;
  }

  85%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    transform:translate(1px, -5px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  90%{
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    transform:translate(2px, -8px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(2px, -8px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}



#conf-a{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confa 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confa {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  15%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(25px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  80%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(33px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(37px, -23px) scale(0.5)rotate(230deg);
  }
}


#conf-b{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confb 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confb {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  12%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(25px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(33px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(37px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(240deg);
  }
}

#conf-c{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confc 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confc {
  0%{
    opacity:0.7;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  18%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(5px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(13px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(17px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(230deg);
  }
}

#conf-d{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confd 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confd {
  0%{
    opacity:0.7;
    transform: translate(-20px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  18%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(-5px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(-8px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-10px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(230deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="footer-tab">
  <!--button-->
  <div class="crtnewgrp-btn">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="p-2"><button type="button" id="add-score-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Add score</button></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--/button-->
</div>

<svg id="mysvg"
     version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 1200 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 800;" xml:space="preserve">
       <g class="confetti-cone">
        <path class="conf0" d="M131.5,172.6L196,343c2.3,6.1,11,6.1,13.4,0l65.5-170.7L131.5,172.6z"/>
        <path class="conf1" d="M131.5,172.6L196,343c2.3,6.1,11,6.1,13.4,0l6.7-17.5l-53.6-152.9L131.5,172.6z"/>

        <path class="conf2" d="M274.2,184.2c-1.8,1.8-4.2,2.9-7,2.9l-129.5,0.4c-5.4,0-9.8-4.4-9.8-9.8c0-5.4,4.4-9.8,9.9-9.9l129.5-0.4
         c5.4,0,9.8,4.4,9.8,9.8C277,180,275.9,182.5,274.2,184.2z"/>
        <polygon class="conf3" points="231.5,285.4 174.2,285.5 143.8,205.1 262.7,204.7    "/>
        <path class="conf4" d="M166.3,187.4l-28.6,0.1c-5.4,0-9.8-4.4-9.8-9.8c0-5.4,4.4-9.8,9.9-9.9l24.1-0.1c0,0-2.6,5-1.3,10.6
         C161.8,183.7,166.3,187.4,166.3,187.4z"/>
        <ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -89.8523 231.0278)" class="conf2" cx="233.9" cy="224" rx="5.6" ry="5.6"/>
        <path class="conf5" d="M143.8,205.1l5.4,14.3c6.8-2.1,14.4-0.5,19.7,4.8c7.7,7.7,7.6,20.1-0.1,27.8c-1.7,1.7-3.7,3-5.8,4l11.1,29.4
         l27.7,0l-28-80.5L143.8,205.1z"/>
        <path class="conf2" d="M169,224.2c-5.3-5.3-13-6.9-19.7-4.8l13.9,36.7c2.1-1,4.1-2.3,5.8-4C176.6,244.4,176.6,231.9,169,224.2z"/>
        <ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -119.0946 221.1253)" class="conf6" cx="207.4" cy="254.3" rx="11.3" ry="11.2"/>
      </g>

       <rect x="113.7" y="135.7" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -99.5348 209.1582)" class="conf7" width="178" height="178"/>
      <line class="conf7" x1="76.8" y1="224.7" x2="328.6" y2="224.7"/>
      <polyline class="conf7" points="202.7,350.6 202.7,167.5 202.7,98.9  "/>
          <!-- here comes the confettis-->

       <circle class="conf2" id="conf-b" cx="195.2" cy="232.6" r="5.1"/>
       <circle class="conf0" id="conf-b" cx="230.8" cy="219.8" r="5.4"/>
       <circle class="conf0" id="conf-c" cx="178.9" cy="160.4" r="4.2"/>
       <circle class="conf6" id="conf-d"cx="132.8" cy="123.6" r="5.4"/>
       <circle class="conf0" id="conf-d" cx="151.9" cy="105.1" r="5.4"/>

       <path class="conf0" id="conf-d" d="M129.9,176.1l-5.7,1.3c-1.6,0.4-2.2,2.3-1.1,3.5l3.8,4.2c1.1,1.2,3.1,0.8,3.6-0.7l1.9-5.5
        C132.9,177.3,131.5,175.7,129.9,176.1z"/>
       <path class="conf6" id="conf-b" d="M284.5,170.7l-5.4,1.2c-1.5,0.3-2.1,2.2-1,3.3l3.6,3.9c1,1.1,2.9,0.8,3.4-0.7l1.8-5.2
        C287.4,171.9,286.1,170.4,284.5,170.7z"/>
       <circle class="conf6" id="conf-c"cx="206.7" cy="144.4" r="4.5"/>
        <path class="conf2" id="conf-c" d="M176.4,192.3h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
        C179.3,191,178,192.3,176.4,192.3z"/>
       <path class="conf2" id="conf-b" d="M263.7,197.4h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
        C266.5,196.1,265.2,197.4,263.7,197.4z"/>
          <!-- yellow-strip-1-->
         <path id="yellow-strip" d="M179.7,102.4c0,0,6.6,15.3-2.3,25c-8.9,9.7-24.5,9.7-29.7,15.6c-5.2,5.9-0.7,18.6,3.7,28.2
        c4.5,9.7,2.2,23-10.4,28.2"/>
       <path class="conf8" id="yellow-strip" d="M252.2,156.1c0,0-16.9-3.5-28.8,2.4c-11.9,5.9-14.9,17.8-16.4,29c-1.5,11.1-4.3,28.8-31.5,33.4"/>
       <path class="conf0" id="conf-a" d="M277.5,254.8h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
        C280.4,253.5,279.1,254.8,277.5,254.8z"/>
       <path class="conf3" id="conf-c" d="M215.2,121.3L215.2,121.3c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3l0,0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7v0
        c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2l0,0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0h0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2v0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7l0,0
        c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1v0C212.5,119.8,214.5,119.8,215.2,121.3z"/>
       <path class="conf3" id="conf-b" d="M224.5,191.7L224.5,191.7c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3v0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7l0,0
        c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2h0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0l0,0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2l0,0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7v0
        c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1l0,0C221.7,190.2,223.8,190.2,224.5,191.7z"/>
       <path class="conf3" id="conf-a" d="M312.6,242.1L312.6,242.1c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3l0,0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7v0
        c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2l0,0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0h0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2v0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7l0,0
        c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1v0C309.9,240.6,311.9,240.6,312.6,242.1z"/>
       <path class="conf8" id="yellow-strip" d="M290.7,215.4c0,0-14.4-3.4-22.6,2.7c-8.2,6.2-8.2,23.3-17.1,29.4c-8.9,6.2-19.8-2.7-32.2-4.1
        c-12.3-1.4-19.2,5.5-20.5,10.9"/>

</svg>
```